# Acessando os elementos HTML no Array

Tags: javascript

Ao utilizar o script, eu estou quebrando uma tabela de `<tr>` com elementos `<td>`. Alguns dos `<tr>` tem o background vermelho e amarelo. Meu Script isola esse elementos no vetor `sla`. Cada elemento do vetor fica com um texto de `<tr>`, cheio de `<td>`. Eu não sei como fazer, mas gostaria de quebrar o `<td>` e fazer um vetor com os valores isolados de cada `<td>`. Como fazer?

```
const chamados = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr'));
const sla = [];
for(i=0;i < chamados.length;i++){
  if(chamados[i].style.backgroundColor == "red" || chamados[i].style.backgroundColor == "yellow"){
    sla.push(chamados[i]);
    for(j=0; j < sla.length; j++){
      console.log(sla[j]);
    }
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente não é necessário esse `Array.from`.

Utilize o `children` para pegar os elementos filhos desse `tr`, que esses filhos são o `td`. Se o td tiver o `backgroundColor == 'red'` ou `backgroundColor == 'yellow'` ele vai armazenar o texto que está no `td` desse `tr` percorrendo um por um.

```js
const chamados = document.querySelectorAll('tr')
const sla = []

for (let i = 0; i < chamados.length; i++){
  if (chamados[i].style.backgroundColor == 'red' || chamados[i].style.backgroundColor == 'yellow'){
  for (let j = 0; j <chamados[i].children.length; j++)
  sla.push(chamados[i].children[j].innerText)
  }
}
console.log(sla)
```

```html
<table>
<tr style="background:red;">
    <td>tr0 td0 red</td>
    <td>tr0 td1 red</td>
    <td>tr0 td2 red</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background:green;">
    <td>tr1 td0 green</td>
    <td>tr1 td1 green</td>
    <td>tr1 td2 green</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background:yellow;">
    <td>tr2 td0 yellow</td>
    <td>tr2 td1 yellow</td>
    <td>tr2 td2 yellow</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

O exemplo do **@NoFace** usando o chidren para pegar os elementos filhos resolve o problema, mas gostaria de sugerir uma abordagem mais funcional e declarativa.

Pra entender mais sobre o *Destructuring* usando no parametro da funcão trVermelhoOuAmarelo você pode dar uma olhada aqui: [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Basicamente ele obtem uma propriedade que está dentro do objeto.
Sobre como funciona o *filter* aqui: [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro).
Sobre o *map* e *flatMap* aqui: [Array.prototype.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). Basicamente o flatMap pega arrays dentro de array e transforma em uma coisa só, se eu tenho [[1,2],3], usando o flatMap eu terei [1,2,3].

```js
const chamados = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr'));

const trVermelhoOuAmarelo = ({ style: { backgroundColor }}) => 
  backgroundColor === 'red' || backgroundColor === 'yellow';
  
const obterInnerText = (element) => element.innerText;
const obterFilhos = (element) => Array.from(element.children);

const sla = chamados
  .filter(trVermelhoOuAmarelo)
  .flatMap(obterFilhos)
  .map(obterInnerText);

console.log(sla);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr style="background:red;">
      <td>0.0 red</td>
      <td>0.1 red</td>
      <td>0.2 red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:green;">
      <td>1.0 green</td>
      <td>1.1 green</td>
      <td>1.2 green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:yellow;">
      <td>2.0 yellow</td>
      <td>2.1 yellow</td>
      <td>2.2 yellow</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Você ainda pode deixar as coisas mais simples já filtrando apenas os elementos vermelhos e amarelos no querySelector, exemplo:

```js
const expression = "tr:not([style*='green'])";
const chamados = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(expression));

const sla = chamados
  .flatMap(x => Array.from(x.children))
  .map(x => x.innerText);

console.log(sla);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr style="background:red;">
    <td>0.0 red</td>
    <td>0.1 red</td>
    <td>0.2 red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:green;">
    <td>1.0 green</td>
    <td>1.1 green</td>
    <td>1.2 green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:yellow;">
    <td>2.0 yellow</td>
    <td>2.1 yellow</td>
    <td>2.2 yellow</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```